# TMultiView popover mode height too large

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I am testing using TMultiView to popup a window with various options. I read about it here on Embarcadero website

[Mobile Tutorial: Using a MultiView Component](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_a_MultiView_Component_to_Display_Alternate_Views_of_Information_(iOS_and_Android))

Now the problem is that popup is working good but its too large. Its not as per what I have it at design time. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was much easier than that I though.

I had to set `PopoverOptions.PopupHeigh` to what ever I want to fix this. For some reason when you reset MultiView size manually, this dosen't automatically change `PopoverOptions.PopupHeigh`. Maybe it's a bug.

Note that `Size.Height` is used when MultiView is in different mode.